# split the SKTextureNode with swipe

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sprite, skspritenode

I'm trying to split `SKTextureNode` into pieces with swipe gesture. I have coordinates of enter and exit.

How can i use this for splitting the node?

Comment: What is an SKTextureNode? Can't find it in Apple's docs.

Comment: this is sprite kit extension of iOs

Comment: Are you trying to build a Fruit Ninja like game?

Comment: not quite like, but sprites need to be cut :)

Comment: Cut into how many pieces?

Comment: into two pieces like slice, than it can be more

Comment: "SKTextureNode" = SKSpriteNode;  common mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using SKPhysicsJointFixed to connect two SKSpriteNodes to form an object. When the user swipes across the object, you split it by removing the joint and apply an impulse to send the pieces in opposite directions. Here's a method to connect two nodes:

```
- (void) connectNode1:(SKSpriteNode *)node1 toNode2:(SKSpriteNode *)node2
{
    CGPoint midPoint = CGPointMake((node1.position.x + node2.position.x)/2,
                                   (node1.position.y + node2.position.y)/2);

    SKPhysicsJointFixed *joint = [SKPhysicsJointFixed jointWithBodyA:node1.physicsBody
                                                               bodyB:node2.physicsBody
                                                              anchor:midPoint];
    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:joint];
}
```

and here's an example of how to split the object if it is touched. This should be replaced with a swipe handler.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        // Determine which node was touched
        SKNode *touchedObject = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

        if (touchedObject == self) continue;

        // Check if node is connected
        if ([touchedObject.physicsBody.joints count]) {
            SKPhysicsJointFixed *joint = [touchedObject.physicsBody.joints firstObject];
            SKSpriteNode *node2 = (SKSpriteNode *)(touchedObject.physicsBody == joint.bodyA ?
                            joint.bodyB.node : joint.bodyA.node);

            [self.physicsWorld removeJoint:joint];
            CGFloat dx = touchedObject.position.x - node2.position.x;
            CGFloat dy = touchedObject.position.y - node2.position.y;

            CGFloat magnitude = sqrtf(dx*dx+dy*dy);

            // unit vector
            dx /= magnitude;
            dy /= magnitude;

            // send nodes in opposite directions
            [touchedObject.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(dx*20, dy*20)];
            [node2.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(-dx*20, -dy*20)];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method associated with SKTexture that can be of help in this case.

```
[SKTexture textureWithRect:someRect inTexture:someTexture];
```

You can use this method by calculating two rects based on the coordinates, and assigning them to two SKSpriteNode objects.

However, this can be used only to generate rectangular cut-outs of the texture in question.

Also, have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKTexture/textureWithRect:inTexture:).

Comment: i need to split it up not just with rect. in any directions, like fruit ninja for example.